# SSL error :"server hello" rejected by client

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I have this client trying to access the web page"https://trackntrace.telepost.gl",
but fails  due to ssl handshake error.
I tried using wget , openssl and also from chrome browser.

I did a tcpdump on both the servers (I have access to both) , and found the server is sending a "server hello" for the "client hello" sent by the client, but the client seems to reject it midway, I mean I dont see the full packet sent by the server.

I am able to access it from my pc and some other servers as well.
and also ssl check on "https://trackntrace.telepost.gl", using different websites like "ssllabs" , "sslchecker" fails saying "No ssl supported".

Any help or lead will be appreciated.

Part of **tcp dump from client and server below**

[image: **tcp dump from client**]

[image: **tcp dump from server**]

Comment: At that stage you will have more insights by running `openssl s_client ... -msg` you will see all TLS messages. You are also not stating versions and software used on both side. It is also not very relevant to a programming website except if you are debugging issues with 2 pieces of software you wrote. Also your wireshark shows TCP retransmission packets which are not a good sign, but not a problem related to TLS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The server is a Microsoft server and I'm just trying to write a client for it. Even as simple  as wget isn't working from the client server which runs on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the packet captures something is sending a RST claiming to be from the server (i.e. from port 443) to the client and a RST claming to be from the client to the server (i.e. to port 443). Also, the response from the server which contains the certificate is not forwarded to the client.

This suggests that there is some middlebox (like a firewall) in between client and server which does deep packet inspection and explicitly breaks the connection between client and server after having a look at the servers certificate. Given I have the same problems as you from my location my guess is that the middlebox is near the server and not near the client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I too had a similar thought because there was a firewall. But connections from other servers are allowed. Even you can try that website.

Comment: And if you see the client dump, in the immediate response after "client Hello" from the server which wireshark termed as ACK I see some certificate details, like part of the certificate.

Comment: @Josh: there comes only a part of the TLS record containing the certificate and not the full record. This can also be seen in your packet capture on the client side: there is a packet with length 1436 coming from the server. My guess is that the middlebox first needs to get the full TLS record to decide if it breaks the connection and until then it will forward any packets. This is a typical behavior of DPI solutions which (compared to a proxy) cannot really defer received packets if they need more data for analysis.

Comment: Sorry am new to this, so I assumed that it's the client that's rejecting it after partially reading the packets.

Comment: But you are saying the other way around , that is the middle box rejecting it.

Comment: The firewall is close to the server and why should it reject the response after looking at the server's certificate,While it allows for others?

Comment: *"While it allows for others"* - does it? I have the same symptoms as you report from my location and your (failed) tests with ssllabs etc suggest that the problem is not restricted to a few source IP only.

Comment: So you mean to say responses to some IPs are only allowed by the middle box?

Comment: Another problem is the network guy who manages the firewall thinks its not the firewall that is causing it, so can you please give me some key points to let the network guy know where to check.

Comment: *"So you mean to say responses to some IPs are only allowed by the middle box?"* - no, I'm saying that I don't know of any source which has access to the site from outside. It might well be that the firewall denies access for all. - *"...some key points to let the network guy know where to check"* - to narrow down where the problem sniff the traffic at various places at the path between client and server. Then you can see at which place the packet from the server is no longer received - that's where the misbehaving middlebox is.

Comment: The website is supposed to be allowed for public use, not sure how they do the blocking for others, may be by IPs in the region or network?
Is this also the behavior of DPI systems you mentioned above?

Comment: btw thank you so much for the clarification, I have been breaking my head all day long for this. Will mark your comment as answered once I solve this with the network guy.